# Connecting DynamoDB from Spark program to load all items from one table using Python?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have written a program to write items into DynamoDB table. Now I would like to read all items from the DynamoDB table using PySpark. Are there any libraries available to do this in Spark?

Comment: We're you able to do this?

Comment: No, I just used what boto documentation has provided without spark.

Comment: I would try to tweak this code - https://github.com/bchew/dynamodump

Comment: Any sample on how you got this to work? sms_1190

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parallel scans](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-parallel-scans-and-other-good-news/) available as part of the [DynamoDB API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Segment) through [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) and a scheme like the parallel S3 file processing application written for PySpark described [here](https://wrightturn.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/getting-spark-data-from-aws-s3-using-boto-and-pyspark/). Basically, instead of reading all the keys a-priori, just create a list of segment numbers and hard code the max number of segments for scan in the `map_func` function for Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to export DynamoDB rows to S3.  You can use a trigger on S3 to kick off Lambda or even process the resulting files manually.  For me the export was a great option since it happened so quickly.  It took about an hour to export 1 TB which is about 1 billion rows.  From there you have complete flexibility in getting it analyzed.